# Jupyter Notebook kernel keeps dying

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda Navigator months ago and have been using it to launch Jupyter Notebooks. Recently, I was trying to import Graphviz to visualize a decision tree and had a ton of trouble getting the package to work. I tried following various command line instructions that I read on forums, but somewhere in following some of those instructions, I must have completely messed up my conda environment. I am no longer able to open Anaconda. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling (followed the directions for uninstalling it from the Anaconda documentation page). Everytime I try to reinstall it, it says the installation has failed or that it already exists on my computer.

I gave up on Anaconda and went ahead installing Jupyter Notebooks on its own. This worked just fine and I'm able to launch a kernel, but every time I try to execute code, it says the kernel has died and will automatically restarted.

I have gone down many rabbit holes...any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have youtried uninstalling  ipykernel  and then reinstalling it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! No I haven't tried this. I'm guessing this could be a potential solve for the repeating dead kernel? I'm weary to start uninstalling and reinstalling things as I believe that's what got me into this mess initially.

Comment: I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling ipykernel and I'm still experiencing the dead kernel.